# Pandas dataframe create new column indicating overlapping values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1, 2],
                   "fields": [["eggs", "apple", "toy", "orange", "bear", "red"], 
                              ["orange", "bear", "red"]],
                   "subfields":[["bear", "red"],["bear", "red"]]})
```

and my expected output is:

| ID | fields | overlap between subfields and fields |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | eggs | N |
| 1 | apple | N |
| 1 | toy | N |
| 1 | orange | N |
| 1 | bear | Y |
| 1 | red | Y |
| 2 | orange | N |
| 2 | bear | Y |
| 2 | red | Y |

is there anyway that I can do this? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple solution.

**Disclaimer:** If you have anything more than ~15 elements in each list, **forget about my solution.**

---

```py
new_df = df.explode('fields')
new_df['overlap between subfields and fields'] = new_df.apply(
    lambda row: row['fields'] in row['subfields'], 
    axis=1
    ).replace({True: 'Y', False: 'N'})

new_df.drop(columns='subfields', inplace=True)
```

Comment: This will however be inefficient to check presence of field in subitems for each item (that's why I used `groupby`+`isin`) ;)

Comment: @mozway, I have timed both approaches for small and large dataframes, and my version seems to be faster in both cases. Maybe grouping takes a lot of time in your version..

Comment: How many items in fields?

Comment: @mozway same as here. Maybe that's the reason

Comment: I guess yes, for few items the overhead of `groupby` is significant

Comment: I also realize you could `groupby` subfields (first converted as frozenset) to improve the `groupby` even more (it seems there are duplicated groups)

Comment: Thanks for the timing, btw I added another way ;)

Comment: @mozway, wow, so creative!  There are so many possibilities to achieve the same result.. And on any dataframe larger than the toy examples, your alternative solution is definitely the fastest one so far!

Answer (score 1):

You can `explode` and use `groupby`:

```
s = df.set_index('ID')['subfields']

out = (df
 .explode('fields')
 .assign(**{'overlap': lambda d: np.where(d.groupby('ID', group_keys=False)
                                           .apply(lambda g: g['fields'].isin(s[g.name]))
                                          , 'Y', 'N'
                                         )
           })
 .drop(columns='subfields') # comment to keep subfields
)
```

output:

```
   ID  fields overlap
0   1    eggs       N
0   1   apple       N
0   1     toy       N
0   1  orange       N
0   1    bear       Y
0   1     red       Y
1   2  orange       N
1   2    bear       Y
1   2     red       Y
```

##### alternative:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[i, set(f).intersection(s)] for i,f,s, in
                    zip(df['ID'], df['fields'], df['subfields'])],
                    columns=['ID', 'fields']
                   ).explode('fields')

new_col = 'overlap'
out = (df.drop(columns='subfields')
         .explode('fields')
         .merge(df2.assign(**{new_col: 'Y'}), how='left')
         .fillna({new_col: 'N'})
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use [`isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html#numpy.isin) that does the checking for each element.

With that its pretty easy to do this:

```
s = df.apply(lambda x: np.isin(x['fields'], x['subfields']), axis=1).explode()
s = np.where(s, 'Y', 'N')
df = df.explode('fields').assign(overlap=s).drop('subfields',axis=1)
```

print(df):

```
   ID  fields overlap
0   1    eggs       N
0   1   apple       N
0   1     toy       N
0   1  orange       N
0   1    bear       Y
0   1     red       Y
1   2  orange       N
1   2    bear       Y
1   2     red       Y
```

Comment: That won't consider groups, however. This wouldn't work if subfields for ID was orange/bear

Comment: I didn't realize OP wanted per group, it wasn't explicit. but I updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_df = df.explode('fields')
new_df
```

[image]

#### use apply for easy and cleaner way

```
def overlap(fields, subfields):
    if fields in subfields:
        return 'Y'
    else:
        return 'N'


new_df['overlap'] = new_df[['fields','subfields']].apply(lambda x:  overlap(x.fields,x.subfields),axis=1)
del new_df['subfields']
new_df
```

[image]